# Deployment to Azure VM using CircleCI

Tags: azure, deployment, build, circleci

I am new to CircleCI and trying to figuring out options to deploy code on Azure VM's.

I am good with build part. but not able to deploy code on Azure VM's. As my VM's are behind the firewall. and i realized that CircleCI IP address changes contentiously, there is no static IP which i can allow in firewall. I am bound to play in firewall zone and cannot allow all traffic to my servers.

Please let me know the way to work with this scenario. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In this scenario you likely want to upload your application somewhere you trust, then have Azure pull it from there. This can be S3, GitHub Releases, another server, Docker Hub, etc. I don't know what kind of application you're running.

Another option is to VPN in if you're allowed to do that.